# Facebook Ads API - Link post new format change

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-ads-api

About a week ago (Sep 13) Facebook presented the new post-link format (which looks much more like the photo-post - larger image, etc).
However, when I upload posts through API (which worked perfectly), I still get posts that look like the old format (while image is cut to a small square) although Facebook-interfaces (direct Facebook ads-creator ; Power-Editor) generate new-format posts as needed.

I did not see any documentation about the new format (this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#links was updated 3 weeks ago). Also, I was not able to easily sniff the power-editor actions and look for API-differences, if such exists.

Will appreciate any idea.
Thanks.

Comment: A tiny update: I noted that I'm using the "picture" field with a URL of a pre-uploaded image, while the power-editor uses the "thumbnail" field (with a direct file-upload, it seems) which is not really part of the API docs.

Answer (score 2):

A generic link ad following the specs here can be created with the following parameters:

```
title=My Link Ad Creative
body=Click Here To Learn More
object_url=http://example.com
image_hash=FfabEOIJWF898203fPOIEJfe0f93f0
```

and `post`ed to the graph API. It will create a smaller, column-like side-bar link ad with only two fields of text—I think that's the "old format...small square" version you're referencing.

To create the newsfeed-like, larger-photo link ad like you're looking for, you'll need to use the new `object_story_spec` parameter and include a valid object story spec so that the link ad (which is really a page post) can be created on the fly and associated with your creative.

An object story spec should contain a `page_id` -- so that the "post" can be created and have a page author and for a `link_ad`, it should have a `link_data` field that contains a JSON object of parameters like `message`, `link`, `name`, `caption`, `description`, `image_hash` and so on. The details can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adcreative/v2.2) if you click on object_story_spec from the known fields table and then click the "link_ad" dropdown. Your final object would look like this:

```
params = {
  page_id: 1111111111,
  link_data: {
    link: 'example.com',
    message: 'The main text below the image',
    name: 'The text at the top of the image'
    description: 'the text below the message',
    image_hash: 'a previously uploaded image hash'
}
```

And your `post` request to create the creative would have the fields:

```
name=My Link Ad Creative
object_story_spec={JSON.stringify(params)}
```

where params are json-encoded.

Make sense?